# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Unity Wave Function Collapse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, generics

I am following a wave function collapse tutorial and wants to modify it a bit. In the tutorial, the **wave function collapse** algorithm(i.e. WFC) used the colors on 4 sides of a prefab to find its possible neighbors that has the same color on at least 1 side of that prefab. The author used **1D array** to calculate the colors on the 4 sides of a prefab. I would like to modify it a bit - I want to use **2D array with [,]** to find all color on 4 sides. However when I play in unity, an error occurs at the method Rotate90, `ColorsLeftNew[row, col] = ColorsBack[row, tileSideVoxels - col - 1];`- "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

````
    public byte[,] ColorsRight;
    public byte[,] ColorsForward;
    public byte[,] ColorsBack;

    public void CalculateSidesColors()
    {
        ColorsLeft = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];
        ColorsRight = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];
        ColorsForward = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];
        ColorsBack = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];

        for (int row = 0; row < tileSideVoxels; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < tileSideVoxels; col++)
            {
                ColorsLeft[row, col] = GetVoxelColor(row, col, Direction.Left);
                ColorsRight[row, col] = GetVoxelColor(row, col, Direction.Right);
                ColorsForward[row, col] = GetVoxelColor(row, col, Direction.Forward);
                ColorsBack[row, col] = GetVoxelColor(row, col, Direction.Back);
            }
        }

    }

    public void Rotate90()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);


        byte[,] ColorsLeftNew = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];
        byte[,] ColorsRightNew = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];
        byte[,] ColorsForwardNew = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];
        byte[,] ColorsBackNew = new byte[tileSideVoxels, tileSideVoxels];

        for (int row = 0; row < tileSideVoxels; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < tileSideVoxels; col++)
            {
                ColorsLeftNew[row, col] = ColorsBack[row, tileSideVoxels - col - 1];
                ColorsRightNew[row, col] = ColorsForward[row, tileSideVoxels - col - 1];
                ColorsForwardNew[row, col] = ColorsLeft[row, tileSideVoxels - col - 1];
                ColorsBackNew[row, col] = ColorsRight[row, tileSideVoxels - col - 1];
                print("Row: " + row + " Col: " + col + " NewCol: " + (tileSideVoxels - col - 1));

                //print("Myfunc: LeftNew: " + ColorsRightNew[row, col]);
                //print("myfunc Back: " + ColorsBack[row, col]);
            }
        }
        ColorsRight = ColorsRightNew;
        ColorsForward = ColorsForwardNew;
        ColorsLeft = ColorsLeftNew;
        ColorsBack = ColorsBackNew;


    }```

The method GetVoxelColor returns a RGB color index. The Rotate90 method rotates the prefab so its sides can match with other prefabs, the rotation type is preset by hand. 

This is soo time consuming, please help!
````

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: sorry about that. My question is what does these code mean, why does c1's function has 2 variabled v1 and v2?

Comment: They are lambda variables.

Comment: @shellypeng "what does the code mean" is not an on-topic question. Do you understand the syntax but have trouble understanding it's purpose? Or you don't understand some syntax? In any case you should elaborate on what you understand and what you don't.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what does these code mean, why does `c1`'s function has 2
> variabled `v1` and `v2`?

This is what's called a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions):

```
(input-parameters) => expression
```

in this case you are calling the [IEnumerable.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) *Extension Method* on an array of `Vector4`.

Here is its signature:

```
public static int Count<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,bool> predicate);
```

The important part in regards to your question is `Func<TSource,bool> predicate)`.

This will be called for every item `TSource` in the array, which is to say it will enumerate through every `Vector4` in your array and call your lambda. The same as `Any`.

You can think of a lambda as just a method or function where the inputs are supplied for you before the `=>`.

As to what this line of code actually does:

```
int c1 = a.Count(v1 => b.Any(v2 => Vector4.Distance(v1, v2) < threshold));
```

It's just giving a count where the Distance between each item in `a` and any item in `b` is below a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking what the following code is doing:

```
int c1 = a.Count(v1 => b.Any(v2 => Vector4.Distance(v1, v2) < threshold));
```

What it is doing is setting the value of `c1` to equal the number of items in the array of `a` which have a distance of less than the value of `threshold` (0.001f) from any item in the array of `b`.

So, if there are any Vector4 values in `a` which are less than `0.001f` away from ANY Vector4 value in `b`, it will count them and the end result of that count is set as the value of `c1`.